# Field is not writable - using formula field in a wrapper

Tags: apex

While creating a instance of wrapper class, which uses a formula field from another object, I get this error.

> Field is not writeable: OrderItem.ReleaseNo__c

Sample wrapper class I am working on

```
public class wrapper{
    public string name;
    public List<OrderItem> products;  // orderItem object has a formula field that I need to use
}
```

And in the class create an instance of the wrapper (I have to query from child-to-parent levels up due to the information I seek)

```
List<CompartmentFrom__c> lstCompartments =
            [SELECT Id, Name, DeliveryLine__r.OrderProduct__r.order.ReleaseNo__c, 
                    DeliveryLine__r.OrderProduct__r.Quantity,
            FROM CompartmentFrom__c ];
        
       
        for(CompartmentFrom__c comp: lstCompartments){
                wrapper wrp= new wrapper();
                wrp.name = comp.Name;
                
                OrderItem product = new OrderItem(Id = comp.DeliveryLine__r.OrderProduct__c, 
                                                ReleaseNo__c = comp.DeliveryLine__r.OrderProduct__r.ReleaseNo__c, 
                                                Quantity = comp.DeliveryLine__r.OrderProduct__r.Quantity);
                wrp.products.add(product); 
        }
```

While assigning `ReleaseNo__c`, I get `Field not writable error`, which I am just using to fill the wrapper instance. Is there any way to get around it?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to clarify - is `ReleaseNo__c` a formula field in the `OrderItem` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to have an SObject instance, then you could just make a wrapper for your OrderItem as well.

```java
public class Wrapper{
    public String name;
    public List<OrderItemWrapper> products;

    // Need to initialize the list before you can add items to it
    public Wrapper(){
        products = new List<OrderItemWrapper>();
    }
}

public class OrderItemWrapper{
    public Id id;
    public String releaseNo;
    public Double quantity;

    // Since it looks like everything comes from your OrderItem, might
    //   as well just pass that into this constructor
    public OrderItemWrapper(OrderItem inputData){
        id = inputData.Id;
        releaseNo = inputData.ReleaseNo__c;
        quantity = inputData.Quantity;
    }

    // And toss in a method to turn it into an OrderItem for good measure
    public OrderItem makeOrderItem(){
        return new OrderItem(Id = id, Quantity = quantity);
    }
}
```

Which you would then use like so (assuming you also query DeliveryLine__r.OrderProduct__r.Id)

```java
for(CompartmentFrom__c comp: lstCompartments){
    Wrapper wrp = new Wrapper();
    wrp.name = comp.Name;
    
    // When you query up a relationship, the "__r" field is a fully fledged
    //   SObject, and you can treat it as such
    wrp.products.add(
        new OrderItemWrapper(comp.DeliveryLine__r.OrderProduct__r);
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Derek , I already working on it. I was thinking if there was any other way out.

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following for this code element

```
for(CompartmentFrom__c comp: lstCompartments){
    wrapper wrp= new wrapper();
    wrp.name = comp.Name;
            
    OrderItem product = 
       (OrderItem) new sfab_FabricatedSObject(OrderItem.class)
           .setField(OrderItem.Id,comp.DeliveryLine__r.OrderProduct__c)
           .setField(OrderItem.ReleaseNo__c, comp.DeliveryLine__r.OrderProduct__r.ReleaseNo__c)
           .setField(OrderItem.Quantity,comp.DeliveryLine__r.OrderProduct__r.Quantity)
           .toSobject();
     wrp.products.add(product); 
    }
```

This uses the [Matt Addy SObjectFabricator](https://github.com/mattaddy/SObjectFabricator) to construct any Sobject (including hierarchy: parent(s) and children) with read-only fields if needed. Underneath, it uses the JSON serialize/deserialize technique to create SObjects in memory.  Highly recommended to add to your arsenal.